# How can i get all the previous months since today?

Tags: react-native, date, momentjs, luxon

How can i do this same function of this with moment js or other library like luxon, i want to get all the previos 'n' months since the current day

for example currently is agost, i need Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, the names should be in short

```js
console.log(getPreviousNMonths(6))
 function uInt(n, ceil) {
    while (n < 0) {
        n += ceil
    }
    return n % ceil
}
function getPreviousNMonths(n) {
    const date = new Date()
    const d = new Date(date.getTime())
    const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], { month: 'short' })
    const names = []

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
        d.setMonth(uInt(d.getMonth() - 1, 12))
        names.push(formatter.format(d))
    }
    return names.reverse()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
const names = []

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
    let monthName =  moment('2021-08-10').subtract(i, "month").startOf("month").format('MM');
    names.push(monthName)
}
```

Or using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

```
const names = []

for (let i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
    let monthName =  DateTime.local().minus({ months: i }).toFormat("MM") 
    names.push(monthName)
}
```

Comment: moment is deprecated, can you change for luxon please

Comment: the names should be in short

Comment: oh well I didn't knew that moment was depreciated, I am still using it

Comment: the names i am getting not like this Jul, Feb, i need in short the names